# Draw illustration in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please tell me, maybe somewhere there is a similar illustration in Tikz, *or how to draw an arbitrary outline with text inside and arrows to the corresponding positions*?

[image]

First of all, I try to create shape simply, using `shapes.symbols`, and shif it in my tikz picture, but it is not work correctly

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [cloud, draw, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=4cm, shift={(5,1)}] at (12.5, 5) {ddfw};
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Lines and nodes (postions of 1,2,3,4)

```
\draw (1,2) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {1};
% Text Node
\draw (2,2) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {2};
% Text Node
\draw (3,2) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {3};
% Text Node
\draw (4,2) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {4};
```

Thus, it remains to understand why the cloud shift does not work and what the position of the beginning and end of the arrows will be...Therefore, I will continue to think for now

**UPD:**

I try to draw this, but if manually to draw this arrows and shpaes, final result is very awful...

If I use @MS-SPO advice, I cant draw correctly shape and arrow, but I think, probably I can automate drawing of arrows and nodes...

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0.6,-1.1) {1};
  \node (B) at (1.4,-1.1) {2};
  \node (C) at (2.2,-1.1) {3};
  \node (D) at (3.0,-1.1) {4};
   \draw[thick] (0.25,-0.65) -- (1,-0.65)  (1cm,1.5ex);
   \draw[thick] (1.1,-0.65) -- (1.7,-0.65)  (1cm,1.5ex);
   \draw[thick] (1.9,-0.65) -- (2.5,-0.65)  (1cm,1.5ex);
   \draw[thick] (2.7,-0.65) -- (3.35,-0.65)  (1cm,1.5ex);
  \draw[arrows = {Stealth[scale=2]-}] (0.5,-0.3) arc (142:90:7.2cm);
  \draw[arrows = {Stealth[scale=2]-}] (1.28,-0.3) arc (150:90:4.22cm);
  \draw[arrows = {Stealth[scale=2]-}] (2.2,-0.3) arc (150:90:2.72cm);
  \draw[arrows = {Stealth[scale=2]-}] (3,-0.3) arc (150:90:1.85cm);
  \node [cloud, aspect = 3, cloud puffs=25, draw, minimum width=7cm, minimum height=3.5cm]
    at (8, 1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You could look at the `cloud` shape from the `shapes.symbols` library.

Comment: And you can use polar coordinates for anchors. When the clouds node is C, the 4 anchors are roughly at C.170 , C.160 , C.180 (or C.west) and C.190 .

Comment: And you could use the `decorations.text` library to place the text on the curved arrows (which you could draw using something like `to[out=180, in=75]`). If you could come up with some code to start with, it will be easier to help you with where you got stuck.

Comment: Does it really *need* a random edge?  You should just use a box or an ellipse...

Comment: It sould be noted that ragged shapes are harder to program than smooth shapes.  You also might look around for a similar frame in clip art.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, use Hobby shortcut]
\node (A) at (-8,-4) {1};
\node (B) at (-7,-4) {2};
\node (C) at (-6,-4) {3};
\node (D) at (-5,-4) {4};
\foreach \n in {A,B,C,D}{
  \draw[cyan!60] ([yshift=2pt]\n.north west) -- ([yshift=2pt]\n.north east);
  \draw[cyan!60, -Stealth] (0,0) to[bend right=2cm]node[black, above, sloped, pos=0.8]{36 choices} ([above=0.5cm]\n);
}
\draw[cyan!60, closed, fill=white] (3,0) \foreach \ang in {5,10,...,355}{ .. ({(3+0.4*rnd)*cos(\ang)}, {(1.5+0.4*rnd)*sin(\ang)})};
\node[align=left] {Pool of available\\symbols: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,\\H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,\\S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z\\0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A random cloud shape with text and arrows]