# Repeat same random number

Tags: tikz-pgf, random-numbers

Answering this question: [Draw illustration in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/711673/draw-illustration-in-tikz/711779#711779) , I wanted to draw a *non-intersecting* stepwise (super-)ellipse with random modified radius. I ended up using essential this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[cyan, very thick] (2.5,0) \foreach \ang in {5,10,...,355}{ -- ({(2+rnd)*cos(\ang)}, {0.5*(2+rnd)*sin(\ang)})} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Random sawtoothed closed loop]

The problem is that the radius in the ellipse is modified with two different random numbers, and the shape does as seen self-intersect. My goal is to have the x-radius be random, `(2+rnd)` and the y-radius be a scale of that, `0.5*(2+rnd)` (but with same random number).

I was thinking, that I could use `\pgfmathparse`, but that is not allowed inside a `\draw`.

How do I solve this problem?

*Edit:* I have just functionally solved my problem. I do not know if it can be done in a smarter way.

Answer (score 2):

Just as I was posting the question, I remembered `\pgfextra` and the solution was simple:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[cyan, very thick] (2.5,0) \foreach \ang in {5,10,...,355}{ \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{(2+rnd)}} -- ({(\r*cos(\ang)}, {0.5*\r*sin(\ang)})} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sawtoothed ellipse]

-but I still do not know if the `rnd` number directly can be reused!?

*Edit:* Now without the extra macro.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[cyan, very thick] (2.5,0) \foreach \ang in {5,10,...,355}{ \pgfextra{\pgfmathrnd} -- ({(2+\pgfmathresult)*cos(\ang)}, {0.5*(2+\pgfmathresult)*sin(\ang)})} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```